# Outcome probabilities for set number of dice rolls with conditional extra rolls

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

If we are allowed $n$ rolls of a dice, where each roll of 1 gives us an extra roll, what is the probability of rolling m 1s in the sequence of available rolls, and likewise what is the probability of rolling m 2s (say)?

(Title and question edited to remove trivial recurrence relation)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula

Comment: @universalset, I did notice the relation resembles that recursive formula for binomial coefficients, and the boundary conditions increase the resemblance, so much so that they're very likely synonymous! But I'm also interested in solutions to the probability problem - Maybe I should just have asked about that.

Comment: Clarification question:  if you roll a 1 on one of your extra rolls, do you get another extra roll?

Comment: @universalset, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without extra rolls, the probability of getting $m$ of any given result out of $n$ rolls is given by the Binomial distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):  in this case, it is $\binom{n}{m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}$, where $p=\frac{1}{6}$ is the probability of rolling a particular number on the die.

Now suppose you begin with $n$ rolls, and whenever you roll a 1, you get an extra roll.  With probability $1$ you will eventually stop rolling your dice, and there will be $n$ total rolls which are *not* 1s. Any of the other values is equally likely for each such roll, so the probability that the number of 2s (3s, etc) is $m$ is given by $\binom{n}{m}q^m(1-q)^{n-m}$, where $q = \frac{1}{5}$.

What about the number of 1s rolled?  This is given by the Negative Binomial distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), where a success is rolling a 1, a failure is any other roll, and we want the number of successes before $n$ failures.  Hence the probability that $m$ 1s are rolled is $\binom{m+n-1}{m}(1-p)^np^m$, where $p = \frac{1}{6}$ is the probability of rolling a 1 on any given roll.

Comment: Very many thanks for your prompt reply - That Negative Binomial Distribution, which I'd never heard of, gets right to the heart of the problem! I wonder if "early stopping", once m 1s or m of a particular "failure" value such as 2 have been rolled, even if further rolls are available, have similar manageable expressions for the probability. I suspect not, as it seems likely those cases would lead to truncated or partial series.